# how should I change the representation (not mimetype) of a resource?

Tags: rest

I'm looking at how I can change the representation of a payload at runtime for varied potential advantages, but I'm not sure how to do it. Specifically collections.

Array of Pairs

```
[{ <resource_uri> : { <entity> }, ...}]
```

Array of Objects

```
[<entity>,...]
```

Array of Resources

```
[<resource_uri>]
```

Map of entities

```
{ <resource_uri> : { <entity> }, ... }
```

My problem is, I'm not sure if I should put these different representations of the sets at different URI's, give them slightly varied mime types, e.g. `application/foomap+json` or perhaps use an optional query parameter `?format=map`, or resource `/entities/map`. The UI is going to hide this, this is for programmatic web service access only (which the "UI's JS will have to call).

Answer (score 1):

First things first you should use MIME/Content types. The client will (should) provide the server with all the data formats it can understand and the server will return the best representation, or complain that it doesn't support any of the client's data format requests. Query strings are generally used for filters on resources that don't fit nicely into URL heirachy (e.g. "/stationary/pens?color=black")

Secondly, it is not the best idea to have lots of similar but slightly different representations of the resource, and I can't really imagine why you would want to do this.

You can always repeat data in your response, if you have a resource with JSON data you can also include the URL to it (in fact you should do this for HATEOS). The client can ignore the data it is not interested in.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Not mime types. Probably query parameters**

When writing REST APIs I usually have the underlying structure of my responses the same, regardless of mime type.  The mime type is just the particular representation of the underlying structure.  This allows for things like caching to not care what the mime type is because the data is the same.

Using a query parameter seems like the best option to provide a way to vary the actual structure in the response.

Although I do like the concept of creating something akin to a view resource which would allow you to restructure and rename other resource responses.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to use different URIs. You can use optionally the prefer header if you want.

I suggest you to use standard generic MIME types, like HAL, JSON-LD, etc... instead of creating custom ones, so your clients won't need to write custom parsers...